# video tag on iPhone with menu on top

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, ios-simulator

I have a simple list of videos in html5 on the iPhone the whole app is in html apart from some native Objective-C which sets up a UIWebView, there is a menu which is animated over the top using jQuery mobile. The problem I have is if I touch on a menu item, the video takes the event instead of the menu item.

There is no problem if I view it in a normal browser on a pc or mac.

```
<div data-role="page" id="videosMenu"> 


    <div data-role="content" id="mainContent" style="text-align: center"> 

        <div id="opaqueOverlay"></div>


        <h1>VIDEOS</h1>


        <table id="videosMenuTable">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" align="left" id="video 1"><video src="images/gallery/videos/grey_exterior_night_640_480/grey_exterior_night_640_480-iphone.m4v" poster="images/gallery/videos/grey_exterior_night_640_480/grey_exterior_night_640_480-th.jpg"/><br/>
                </td>
                <td valign="top" align="left" id="video 2"><video src="images/gallery/videos/interior_640_480/interior_640_480-iphone.m4v" poster="images/gallery/videos/interior_640_480/interior_640_480-th.jpg"/></br>
                </td>
                <td valign="top" align="left" id="video 3"><video src="images/gallery/videos/white_exterior_day_640_480/white_exterior_day_640_480-iphone.m4v" poster="images/gallery/videos/white_exterior_day_640_480/white_exterior_day_640_480-th.jpg"/><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>VIDEO ONE</td>
                <td>VIDEO TWO</td>
                <td>VIDEO THREE</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" align="left" id="video 4"><video src="images/gallery/videos/white_exterior_studio_640_480/white_exterior_studio_640_480-iphone.m4v" poster="images/gallery/videos/white_exterior_studio_640_480/white_exterior_studio_640_480-th.jpg"/><br/>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>VIDEO FOUR</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <div class="menu" id="menu_gen">
            <p>MENU</p>
            <ul>
                <li class="explore" rel="explore">EXPLORE</li>
                <li class="galleryMenu" rel="galleryMenu">GALLERY</li>
                <li class="videosMenu" rel="videosMenu">VIDEOS</li>
                <li class="featuresMenu" rel="featuresMenu">FEATURES</li>

            </ul>                                           
        </div>

        <div class="menu" id="menu_next">
            <p>NEXT STEPS</p>
            <ul>
                <li rel="shareMenu">SHARE</li>                  
            </ul>                                           
        </div>          

    </div>

</div>
```

Above is the markup for the videos, not very elegant I know. Any I was hoping that someone might be able to give me some ideas of where to look and what kinds of things can cause an item that appears underneath another item to take the interaction instead of the menu item which is sitting on top of the video items.

Comment: thats nice. any code to go along with this mysterious app?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added the html showing the markup of the videos. Im not really sure I can show enough code as i would have to chop bits out all over the place. Any ideas why I cant get clicks from an element that is visually in front of a video element? The video always takes it as a click on that which is underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this seems to be a known issue and there are several posts on Stack that demonstrate people have had issues with links appearing over video tags on iphone and ipad.

I worked around this by detecting when my menu was open using jQuery. Then I found the poster attr from each video, and stored it, then did a replace on each video to show the poster as an img tag.

Next I detect when the menu is closed, and put back the poster in the video tags, so the user just sees the play button disappear when menu is open, making them think they can't click the video, it works for me.